# Spring MVC responsebody RestTemplate Connection refused localhost

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, junit

RestTemplate is not working and throwing Connection refused exception. Not sure what's the issue on my personal computer where i use wireless internet and there's no proxy involved.

Junit test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:testContext.xml")
public class RestServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testRestService() {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/hello/world", String.class);

        String responseTask = response.getBody();
    }
}
```

test-context.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello/{message}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String sayHello(@PathVariable String message) {
        return "Hello "+message;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
<spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
<jackson.version>2.3.2</jackson.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

exception

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8080/hello/world":Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: what is your application context? Is it ROOT under your web server?

Comment: i tried all possible combinations with the context as well as host such as localhost, 127.0.0.1 and local ip.

Comment: What is the name of your web app? Have u tried adding that your URL?

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Comment: I assumed using RESTTemplate would start an in-memory jetty, but i found out now that it wont and i need to start the server myself. This question is obsolete if my understanding is correct or unless there is a better way of doing it.